# how to send two forms with one click (script ninjaforms id)

Tags: plugins, javascript, buttons

i need the user to send 2 forms with one button-click, so i'm basically trying to merge two buttons into a third one, in order to pass data along, but don't know what i'm doing wrong here.

i've been trying to get [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7843355/submit-two-forms-with-one-button) to work, but i get console-error

> "uncaught typeerror: cannot read property 'submit' of null at
>   SubmitForms"

one of the forms is generated with ninjaforms, the other one by another plugin... i'm not sure if i can address/call the ninjaform id or its name in the right way. where is any of the two to be found? i tried many different variations, all with the same result.

so, my (third) button is hooked in like this:

```
...
function button() {
echo '<input type="button" name=button class=button value="click me" onclick="submitForms()" />';
}
```

and this is what the js looks like (in header):

```
    <script>
submitForms = function(){
    document.getElementById("ninja_form_id_2").submit();
    document.getElementById("id_form_2").submit();
}
</script>
```

i never used javascript before, so i'm not sure if i implemented it like i should.
thanks for help!

Comment: first java != javascript. next you should use ajax for this or combine the 2 forms.

Comment: that's the problem, i can't access the plugin-generated form in order to just change it. if so i would not try to find a workaround. so how would it work with ajax? i'm no dev...

Answer (score 0):

I [partially stole this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960240/jquery-ajax-submit-form#6960586) from SO

```
$("#idForm").submit(function(e) {

var url = "path/to/your/script.php"; // the script where you handle the form input.

$.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: url,
       data: {
                 form1: $("#idForm").serialize(),
                 form2: $("#idForm2").serialize()
       },  
                 // serializes the form's elements.
       success: function(data)
       {
           alert(data); // show response from the php script.
       }
     });

e.preventDefault(); // avoid to execute the actual submit of the form.
});
```

So basically you prevent the normal submit of your forms, serialize it's content to json and send that in an ajax call to the server.

Comment: well, thank you. unfortunately i have no clue what to do with this. i have no "script to handle the input" and as i said i don't know where to get the ninjaforms-id from... can you clarify that for a complete beginner? i'd appreciate it! thanks.

Comment: isn't this why this website exists? to learn?